# Server Time using VBScript and ASP Classic

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I created an application to show a press release once the target date and time have been reached and wanted to know if this is getting the time from the server or the client because I'd like to use the server's time so that someone doesn't just change their clock in order to see it.

Here's my code:

```
    <%
dim strDate
dim strTime
dim strTarget_time
dim strTarget_date
dim strBreak
dim strRuleBreak
dim strToday

strDate = Date()
strTime = Time()
strright_now = Now()
strTarget_time = "3:27:00 PM"
strTarget_date = "6/26/2012"
strBreak = "<br />"
strRuleBreak = "<br /><hr><br />"
strToday = Now()

response.write("<h2>TEST VARIABLES</h2>")
response.write("<p><strong>Today's date:</strong> " & strDate & strBreak)
response.write("<strong>Current time:</strong> " & strTime & strBreak)
response.write("<strong>Target date:</strong> " & strTarget_date & strBreak)
response.write("<strong>Target time:</strong> " & strTarget_time & "</p>")
response.write(strRuleBreak)

'TIME TESTER
response.write("<h2>TIME TESTER</h2>")
response.write("<p><nobr>Testing to see if it is past the target time of: " & strTarget_time & "</nobr></p>")
if strTime >= cdate(strTarget_time) then
response.write("<p>Yes, it is now " & Now() & ", which <strong>IS</strong> past the target time of: " & strTarget_time & "</p>")
else
response.write("<p>No, it is now " & Now() & ", which is <strong>NOT</strong> past the target time of: " & strTarget_time & "</p>")
end if

response.write(strRuleBreak)

'DATE TESTER
response.write("<h2>DATE TESTER</h2>")
response.write("<p><nobr>Testing to see if it is past the target date of: " & strTarget_date & "</nobr></p>")
if strToday >= cdate(strTarget_date) then
response.write("<p>Yes, it is now " & Now() & ", which <strong>IS</strong> past the target date of: " & strTarget_date & "</p>")
else
response.write("<p>No, it is now " & Now() & ", which is <strong>NOT</strong> past the target date of: " & strTarget_date & "</p>")

end if 
response.write(strRuleBreak)

'DATE AND TIME TESTER
response.write("<h2>DATE AND TIME TESTER</h2>")
response.write("<p><nobr>Testing to see if it is past the target of: " & strTarget_date & "&nbsp;-&nbsp;" & strTarget_time & "</nobr></p>" & strBreak)
if strToday >= cdate(strTarget_date) AND strTime >= cdate(strTarget_time) then
response.write("<p>Yes, it is now " & Now() & ", which <strong>IS</strong> past the target of: " & strTarget_date & "&nbsp;-&nbsp;" & strTarget_time & "</p>")
else
response.write("<p>No, it is now " & Now() & ", which is <strong>NOT</strong> past the target of: " & strTarget_date & "&nbsp;-&nbsp;" & strTarget_time & "</p>")

end if 
response.write(strRuleBreak)

%>
```

So in this case, if the time and date is AFTER 6/26/2012 3:27 PM, then the section will show. I'm mainly asking because I want to clarify whether this is client or server side time being used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is going to be server-side, as that is where ASP code is executed.  In order to get the client-side datetime, you would need to use a script to run in the browser - generally JavaScript.